# Bootstrap modal.js. Закрытие предыдущего модального окна

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Добрый день! У меня есть страница, на которой при клике на ссылку Read more выскакивает модальное окно. Таких элементов на странице много и при клике на нескольких ссылках вылазит несколько окон. Можно ли сделать так, что при клике на след. ссылку Read more предыдущее окно закрывалось?!
P.S. У модальных окон разные id

```
<a class="excerpt" href="#modal<?php echo $categories_item->cat_ID; ?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo substr($categories_item->description, 0, 40) ?><br><span>Read more</span></a>
            <div id="modal<?php echo $categories_item->cat_ID; ?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $categories_item->cat_name; ?></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p><?php echo $excerptcat ?></p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Это скрее всего из-за того, что я через стили убирал затемнение у модального окна, потому что оно работает не правильно - сам блок `<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>` появляется в самом низу `<body>` и затемняет всё окно. Почему это может быть?

Comment: какое же оно модальное, если вы в другую ссылку на исходной странице можете кликнуть? Вот вам [пример](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) кликаете вне окна - оно закрывается, это модальное. Так что либо новый диалог открывается из текущего,  либо у вас неправильно сформирован код для диалоговых окошек.

Comment: Добавил в старт-пост код этого окна

Comment: посмотрите внимательно на примеры, везде структура `.modal  > .modal-dailog > .modal-content > .modal-header`  а у вас почему-то из этой цепочки только начало и конец присутствуют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался... добавил следующий код под модальным окном

```
<script>$('#myModal').appendTo("body");</script>
```

Comment: отметьте Ваш ответ как решение Вашего вопроса